# Nginx Error Logs - 'No such file or directory' for an url that seems to load correctly?

Tags: nginx, log, not-found

In the course of trying to discover the cause of a sudden slow down on my Magento 1.9 hosted at Cloudways, I started examining the error logs and can't understand why there are so many 'No such file or directory errors. When I paste the requested URL myself, I get the correct page, but the Nginx log then records it as an error.

What can I infer from this? Is there another reason for this error besides not being found? For example, if the database was too busy, maybe the request timed out? Not sure where to go from here.